coredumpctl does not show latest dumps
I was debugging some segmentation fault and wanted to get the core dumps. I noticed that coredumpctl did only show a dump from 2024/10/29 but not today.
I found that ulimit -c was configured with 0 for some reason (it did work previously) but did not today. So I changed the value. Now the application at least reported that the core was dumped (which it did not previously). I found via cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern that it was set to core so the dump file is located in the same folder. I found this command echo "/tmp/core_dumps/core.%e.%p" | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern which allowed me (after creating the core_dumps-folder to collect the dumps at one location. It seems that in theory, the command echo "|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %e" | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern should be even for useful as it seems to enable using of coredumpctl again. But it still listed only the old dump.
It seems that it should work to use the command systemctl status systemd-coredump to get the status of the thing that manages the recording (and supplying to coredumpctl). But I only get this error:
Unit systemd-coredump.service could not be found.

systemd-coredump is installed, but it can not be found (for example via where systemd-coredump).
So how can I configure my system to give me the core dumps (via coredumpctl)?
